# How to get value from excel file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file like this :

[image: excel file]

I want to get both of the values by using a for-loop and then access them from outside the for-loop. 
Both will be used as a value of xml element.
I have written a code like this :

```
        String longSec = null;
        Double long_sec = null;
        int column_long_sec = 33;
        int c;

        for(c=1; c<=2; c++) {

                row = sheet.getRow(c);

                    long_sec = row.getCell(column_long_sec).getNumericCellValue();
                    longSec = Double.toString(long_sec);
        }   

        Element sid_long_sec = document.createElement("SID_LONG_SEC");
        document.appendChild(sid_long_sec);
        sid_long_sec.appendChild(document.createTextNode(longSec));
```

The code give an output like this:

```
<SID_LONG_SEC>54.61</SID_LONG_SEC>
```

But, I want the code gives the output like this:

```
<SID_LONG_SEC>48.94</SID_LONG_SEC>
<SID_LONG_SEC>54.61</SID_LONG_SEC>
```

How to do that?

Any idea or help will be greatly appreciated

Best Regards,

Yunus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing it all inside the loop?

```
    String longSec = null;
    Double long_sec = null;
    int column_long_sec = 33;
    int c;

    for(c=1; c<=2; c++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(c);
        long_sec = row.getCell(column_long_sec).getNumericCellValue();
        longSec = Double.toString(long_sec);
        Element sid_long_sec = document.createElement("SID_LONG_SEC");
        document.appendChild(sid_long_sec);
        sid_long_sec.appendChild(document.createTextNode(longSec));
    }
```

If you want to leave the XML handling outside the loop, you have to store the values read from the excel file in some container (array or Collection) and then create another loop in which you'll iterate over that container and write the values to the XML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion, but can you help with code?

Comment: @yunus You're welcome. I did include code. Or do you want the alternative implementation?

Comment: I mean code to do what you suggested, that is store the values read from the excel file in a container then create another loop to iterate over that container and write the values to the XML. 
I'm getting stuck there.

If you have the alternative implementation, what kind of alternative is that?

Answer (score 4):

you´re creating the element outside the loop, so it only takes the last value of longSec.

this

```
Element sid_long_sec = document.createElement("SID_LONG_SEC");
document.appendChild(sid_long_sec);
sid_long_sec.appendChild(document.createTextNode(longSec));
```

should be inside the loop

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew it, but I need to create the element outside the loop :)